# SAS - Remove duplicated words in a string

Tags: sas

string = "spanner, span, spaniel, span";
From this string I would like to remove all the duplicates keeping one occurrence of the word and then output the revised string using SAS.
The revised string should look like this:
var string = "spanner, span, spaniel";

Comment: For SO you need to show what you've tried and how you've approached the problem.

Comment: Does it matter which duplicates are removed? Does the order of the words within the string need to be preserved?

Comment: Thank you.  No and no.  I responded to Robert below that might explain my trouble.

Answer (score 1):

```
data a;
    string = "spanner,span,spaniel,span,abc,span,bcc";
    length word $100;
    i = 2;
    do while(scan(string, i, ',') ^= '');
        word = scan(string, i, ',');
        do j = 1 to i - 1;
            if word = scan(string, j, ',') then do;
                start = findw(string, word, ',', findw(string, word, ',', 't') + 1, 't');
                string = cats(substr(string, 1, start - 2), substr(string, start + length(word)));
                leave;
            end;
        end;
        i = i + 1;
    end;
    keep string;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, Robert.  Does the code work only for the specific example above?  It works, but it does not work when I replaced it with real data.  My real data has several rows and a Sentiment column = "I hate the product.  I hate it because it smells bad.  I hate wasting money."  With Dedupped_Sentiment = "I hate the product.  it because smells bad.  wasting money."  My goal is to dedup within the string of a single record so at the end I do not count "hate" 50x just because it was mentioned 50x by one person.

Comment: My code it's a simple example, how to resolve your problem. It works only on specific data. In this case a separator between words is comma. You should change it to some others e.g. space. You have to understand how it works, and write your own solution or change mine.

Answer (score 1):

First create a data set with one column containing the words. With *cats()* the space is eliminated.

```
data temp(keep=text);
  string = "spanner, span, spaniel, span";
  do i=1 to count(cats(string),",")+1;
    text = scan(string,i);
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Eliminate duplicates with nodup (nodupkey also works).

```
proc sort data=temp nodup;    
  by text;
run;
```

Create a macro variable *new_string* with the unique words.

```
proc sql noprint;
  SELECT text
  INTO :new_string separated by ","
  FROM temp
  ;
quit;
```

---

Better solution for new specifications:

```
data temp(keep=i text);
  string = tranwrd("I hate the product. I hate it because it smells bad. I hate wasting money.","."," .");      do i=1 to count(string," ")+1;
    text = scan(string,i," ");
    if text ne "" then do;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

proc sort data=temp;    
  by text i;
run;

data temp2;
  set temp;   
  by text i;
  if first.text OR text eq ".";
run;

proc sort data=temp2;    
  by i;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  SELECT text
  INTO :new_string separated by ","
  FROM temp
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Robert. Just wanted to let you know I found a flaw in your Code. The inner loop modifies the string by removing the duplicate word, but the outer loop checks the next position of the original string no matter what. Example: "A,B,C,B,B" becomes "A,B,C,B" because the inner loop removes the fourth B and then the outer loop doesn't find the last "B" because it moved to the position of the fourth "B".

My solution:

```
data a;
    string = "spanner,span,spaniel,span,abc,span,bcc";
    length word $100;
    i = 2;
    do while(scan(string, i, ',') ^= '');
        hit = 0;
        word = scan(string, i, ',');
        do j = 1 to i - 1;
            if word = scan(string, j, ',') then do;
                start = findw(string, word, ',', findw(string, word, ',', 't') + 1, 't');
                string = cats(substr(string, 1, start - 2), substr(string, start + length(word)));
                hit = 1;
                leave;
            end;
        end;
        if hit = 0 then i = i + 1;
    end;
    keep string;
run;
```

Comment: In general it is easier to just build up a NEW variable that has the list of unique words.  Then there is no need to worry about removing words from a string or changing counters.

Answer (score 0):

Build the list of unique words into a new variable.

```
data test;
  input string $80.;
  length newstring $80;
  do i=1 to countw(string,',');
    if not findw(newstring,scan(string,i,','),',','t') then
      newstring=catx(', ',newstring,scan(string,i,','))
    ;
  end;
cards;
spanner, span, spaniel, span
;
```